# Tracking only scaled versions of uploaded images in FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader, image-scaling

I am working with Azure to try to upload resized images to the storage. I only want to upload a couple of scaled sizes of the original image without uploading the original image. I am able to do this just fine via this code:

```
scaling: {
          sendOriginal: false,

            sizes: [
                { name: "origscaled", maxSize: 800 },
                { name: "thumb", maxSize: 100 }
            ]
        },
```

However, the problem is that "qqparentuuid" is not sent if "sendOriginal" option is set to false. So I am trying to see if there can be any other way for me to link "origscaled" to "thumb" image?

p.s. I really don't need the original image as these are expected to be  > 3MB in size and will be a pain for mobile users.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: Why not just use the file name to link the scaled versions together?

Comment: Hi Ray, yes, I see it. But a guid would be so much easier. File name just doesn't feel like a solid hook. User's could technically rename the file, to a file that was already uploaded with the same name, and that would cause problems. I would also have to strip out "thumb" and "origscaled" out of file names which is trivial, but still I'd rather not do. A "guid" like you are already using "qqparentuuid", is a perfect solution. Was there a technical reason why it was decided not to send it when "sendOriginal" is set to false?

Comment: _"Was there a technical reason why it was decided not to send it when "sendOriginal" is set to false?"._ There is no original file sent to the server, so sending the UUID of a file that the server doesn't know about doesn't make much sense. Your other option is to `setParams` on the scaled versions, including whatever information you need to further identify or categorize them server-side. If you are looking for something else, please open up a feature request.

Comment: I see what you are saying and it makes perfect sense not to send it if no original file is sent to the server. But it could be a nice feature to be able to include some kind of an Id to all resized instances of an image. I will add a feature request just as you've suggested:) Thanks Ray.

Comment: Hi Ray, I've added a feature request for this. I've never used a github feature request before and don't know how to mark it as an "enhancement", I just don't want to post it as a bug by accident and upset anybody;) p.s. thanks for fixing code formatting on this post:))